# How do I get AVG of enum data type in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I tried to get average rating from my **review** table with following query:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM review;
```

Gives me following error:

```
[2020-07-27 11:42:10] [42883] ERROR: function sum(review_rating_enum) does not exist
```

My rating enum type is:

```
create type review_rating_enum as enum ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
```

Are there ways to get AVG from Postgres, with this setting?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I agree. I wish I had found out sooner about that. I think, I will follow your recommendation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first have to cast the enum to text, then you can cast it to an integer (because there is no direct cast from enum to int).

```
select avg(rating::text::integer)
from review;
```

---

But an enum is a really bad choice for such a column. It should be an `integer` (or `smallint`) column together with a check constraint to limit the allowed values.

You can change the type without losing the data like this:

```
alter table review
   alter rating type integer using rating::text::integer;
   
alter table review
   add constraint check_rating check (rating in (1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: New to postgre. I realize my mistake now. Thanks for the query. It works. But, I think I will change the column type to `smallint` like you suggested.

Comment: @priosshrsth: the database is called PostgreSQL or just [Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F) not "postgre".